# How to render element depends on selected option?

Tags: django, reactjs

i'm newbie in react js , and i want to have a form with select options 
i want that when user click on each option , each option render different elements

```js
class Resepy extends Component {
    state = {
        Resepy : 'default'
    }
    render() { 
        
       return = (
            <div className="Resepy">

            
            <form>
            <select id="id_field1" name="field1" onChange={(e) => this.state.Resepy = "Burger"}>
                <option value="default">Food type not selected</option>
                <option value="burger" onClick={(e) => this.setState({  Resepy: 'Burger'  })}>Burger</option>
                <option value="pizza"  onClick={(e) => this.setState({  Resepy: 'Pizza'  })}>Pizza</option>
                </select>
                <div className="food">
                { this.state.Resepy === "burger" ? <div className="burger"></div> //can return any html
                     : <div className="default">default</div>
                    }
                <div className="pizza"></div>
                <div className="food-detail"></div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Add to tray</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
}
}
 
export default Resepy;
```

Comment: Additionally your render method must always have 'return ();' statement or it would render nothing

Comment: @Aykhan yes, edited summery

Comment: is there a reason to use 1 name for 4 different things? also, `<div>` element does not support a property `Resepy`, what are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: @Aprillion i wants that users select on for example burger then react render burger element and also render other elements like this

Comment: Current problem is that you compare Resepy with "burger" but set it to "Burger". Watch out for cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General ternary operator used for more readable code.

Like this:

```
<form>//can be any element
 { codition == true ? <div>It is true</div> //can return any html
                     : <div>It is false</div>
}
</form>
```

Tested, working. Problem was with onClick method option cannot invoke that event.

```
class Resepy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected : 'default'
    };
  }

  setSelected = (event) => {
      let select = document.getElementById("id_field1");
    this.setState({selected: select.value});
      //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = select.value;
  }

  render() { 
       return (
            <div className="Resepy">
             <h1>Something</h1>
             <form>
              <select id="id_field1" name="field1" onChange={this.setSelected}>
                  <option value="default">Food type not selected</option>
                  <option value="burger">Burger</option>
                  <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
                  </select>
                <div id="test"></div>
                  <div className="food">{
                   (this.state.selected === "default") ? 
                       <div className="default">Default</div>
                       : (this.state.selected === "burger") ?
                        <div className="burger">Burger</div>
                         : <div className="pizza">Pizza</div>
                  }</div>
                  <button type="submit">Add to tray</button>
                  </form>
             </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: right, but now i need to display an element when user for example clicked on burger : display my burger element ...

Comment: but i don't want to render the value, i want to render a html element depends on value :) can u fix it?

Comment: can we store a html dom infront of ```onclick state set? ``` and let setSelected() render that dom!?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, fixed now. Was testing if the event was working at all and forgot to change it back. My bad :D

Comment: Aykhan, Worked well :) can we chat somewhere for discussions? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time understanding you, but the most likely thing you could be trying to achieve with the following code from your original question:

> `<div className="burger" Resepy={this.state.Resepy === 'burger'}></div>`

is:

```
<div className="food">
  <div className={this.state.Resepy} />
</div>
```

---

Working example (but I am using Hooks instead of a class component):

```js
const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState('default')
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={selected} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option>default</option>
        <option>burger</option>
        <option>pizza</option>
      </select>
      <div className="food">
        <div className={selected}>{selected}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.default { color: gray; }
.burger { color: orange; }
.pizza { color: red; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: maybe i'm answering bad or i d k , and now i don't know what to answer or ...

Comment: could you help me to create a form that has select options and  each select option renders they'r own Html element? // did i ask this true ? :))

Comment: I added a working example how to use React state with `<select>`, but I am more familiar with Hooks syntax at this point (it would be similar with a class)

Comment: can u fix new question?

Answer (score 0):

Now i want to render html elements depends on values , i tried this but it shows just [Object Object]

```js
  setSelected = (event) => {
      let select = document.getElementById("id_field1");
      document.getElementById("food").innerHTML =          
                        select.value == "default" ? 
                       <div className="default">Default</div>
                       : select.value == "Burger" ?
                        <div className="burger">Burger</div>
                         : <div className="pizza">Pizza</div>
                  
  }
```